# cannot ssh azure ubuntu vm

Tags: azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine

Several days ago, I restart my ubuntu VM. After that, I can't SSH my azure ubuntu VM again. But, port 80 still can be normally accessible from browser.

I already tried to restart, start-stop, reset remote access, and also remove ssh known-hosts in the SSH client. But there is nothing happen.

I also tried to create another ubuntu VM, it works perfectly normal. But when I try to remote the problematic ubuntu VM, it also can't accessible.

this is the error message: "ssh: connect to host xxxxx.cloudapp.net port 22: Operation timed out"

Hopefully there will be any help / suggestion that can be given here to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if you solved that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem earlier today. I had to restart the VM from the Azure Portal before I could ssh in again.

Comment: I already restart it from azure portal but unfortunately I still can't ssh the VM

Answer (score 0):

First, has anything changed before the reboot? Did you install any packages, modify any configuration file, update anything ..?

1. We know the IP did not change (which happens if you STOP a VM without setting it as static first)
2. Have any of the firewall rules changed (either on the VM or in the Network Security Group definition on Azure)?
3. Where are you connecting from? As in is there a notable difference between where you are trying this from and where you were back when it was working?
4. How did you add your SSH key to the VM? Was it at creation time (public key), or later in .ssh/id_rsa ...?